# GCC Make Link Issue

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

i'm trying to execute make on [HTR-toolsUtils](https://www.prhlt.upv.es/tutorials/icfhr2010/HTR-toolsUtils.tar.bz2) and i face the following issue :

```
gcc -g -Wall -lm  -I./include -o pgmmedian pgmmedian.c libpgm.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CALC_MEDIAN", referenced from:
      _main in pgmmedian-7918de.o
  "_MERGE_SLICE", referenced from:
      _main in pgmmedian-7918de.o
  "_SORT_SLICE", referenced from:
      _main in pgmmedian-7918de.o
  "_pgm_getuint", referenced from:
      _pgm_readpgminitrest in libpgm.o
      _pgm_readpgmrow in libpgm.o
  "_pgm_writepgmrowplain", referenced from:
      _pgm_writepgmrow in libpgm.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [pgmmedian] Error 1
```

Makefile :

```
#
# CONFIGURABLE OPTIONS
#

#CC =           cc
CC =            gcc

#CFLAGS =       -O3 -I.
CFLAGS =        -g
WFLAGS =        -Wall
LDFLAGS =       -lm
#LDFLAGS =       -s

BINARIESDIR =        $(HOME)/bin
SCRIPTSDIR  =        $(HOME)/scripts
EXAMPLESDIR =        $(HOME)/CATTI-Examples

...
```

I'm running on OSX El Captain . I read some questions suggesting to run with g++ instead of gcc but had no luck

with gcc -lstdc++ i get the same error and with g++ ( by changing them in the Makefile ) i get :

```
clang: warning: treating 'c' input as 'c++' when in C++ mode, this behavior is deprecated
pgmskew.c:24:10: fatal error: 'values.h' file not found
#include <values.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [pgmskew] Error 1
```

➜  gcc -v

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Any suggestions ? thanks in advance .

Comment: You've tagged this question [tag:c++] but you're compiling a C file, is that right? Also you are **not** using GCC, you are using Apple's fake GCC, which is Clang. This has nothing to do with GCC.

Comment: _"I read some questions suggesting to run with g++ instead of gcc but had no luck"_ I assume those questions were about completely different errors, so why do you think that would be appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some library that defines those symbols. You need to find out what library `libpgm.o` needs and link to it.